# R lubridate round ymd_hms to imd_hm

Tags: r, lubridate, posixct

I have a variable with sunset times (ymd_hms) in my dataframe that I would like to round to the nearest minute.

I've tried the following, but my dates (POSIXct format) are unchanged.

```
    head(df$sunset)
    [1] "2018-07-22 00:20:54 UTC" "2018-07-22 00:20:54 UTC" "2018-07-22 00:20:54 UTC" "2018-07-08 00:24:32 UTC"
    [5] "2018-07-08 00:24:33 UTC" "2018-07-08 00:24:33 UTC"

        output <- df %>%
          mutate(lubridate::round_date(sunset, unit="hour")

    head(output$sunset)
    [1] "2018-07-22 00:20:54 UTC" "2018-07-22 00:20:54 UTC" "2018-07-22 00:20:54 UTC" "2018-07-08 00:24:32 UTC"
[5] "2018-07-08 00:24:33 UTC" "2018-07-08 00:24:33 UTC"
```

What do I need to add to get this to work?

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`.

Comment: first, your unit has to be minute. now you are rounding to the nearest hour. Also, you need to assign the mutate, like `df %>% mutate(rounded_dates = lubridate::round_date(sunset, unit="minute")`

Comment: @phiver Thanks assigning the mutate did the trick!  If you put this as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the change in the mutate. If you do not use the assign in the mutate dplyr will create a column with the header the same as your whole function.

```
df %>% 
  mutate(rounded_dates = lubridate::round_date(sunset, unit="minute"))
```

examples of mutate without and with assigning, see column name in the end:

```
iris %>% 
  mutate(Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width)

    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width
1            5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     setosa                        8.6
2            4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2     setosa                        7.9
.....


iris %>% 
   mutate(addition = Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width)

    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species addition
1            5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     setosa      8.6
2            4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2     setosa      7.9
```